# Distinction between “bend” and “bow”

Tags: difference, verbs, word-difference, lyrics

The nursery rhyme [“London Bridge is Falling Down”](https://www.historicmysteries.com/london-bridge-is-falling-down/) includes a line

> Iron and steel will bend and bow

To me as a non-native speaker, both [“bend”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bend) and [“bow”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bow) evoke essentially the same kind of mental image in this context. Is there a difference which can be put into words? Or are they fully synonymous here, and just combined for the sake of the rhyme?

Writing this I realized that while apparently both words work for iron and steel (perhaps with some artistic liberty?), I'd only *bow* to a king and *bend* rays of light using a lens, not the other way round. But I don't know *why*, except that I'm copying phrases I have read in these contexts. So perhaps an explanation of situations where just one word is appropriate can help point out distinguishing nuances for situations where both are possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bend is a much more common word than Bow.

There are several related words written "bow"

There is is /bau/  rhyming with cow (noun, verb) which is a lowering your body to show humility, for example before a King.

There is /bau/ (noun) The front part of a boat.

There is /bou/ rhyming with know (noun) a knot made with loops of string, for example to tie up a shoes or a gift.

There is /bou/ (noun) Used to shoot an arrow, or play a violin

There is /bou/ (verb) meaning "bend".  This is quite rare, as it can nearly always be replaced by the word "bend".

The verb "bow", meaning "bend", is normally used without an object:

> The beams holding up the roof are bowing

Bend can be used both with or without an object:

> The robot bent the steel bar with ease.
>
> The beams holding up the roof are bending.

(Transitive use of "bow" is possible, but even rarer)

Some slight difference is that "bowing" suggests gentle curving, whereas "bend" might suggest an angular bend, or a fold.

In the rhyme, they are nearly fully synonymous. They are used for the alliteration.  Using redundant words like this is technically called "pleonasm".  For example if I say "You will get a free gift." The word "gift" implies "free", but I might choose to use the redundant word for style or emphasis.

Comment: I think this is a good answer so won't add my own. But I think the distinction between bend and bow has less to do with "gentle" and more to do with curves vs. angles. _Bow_ raises visions of curved things and _bend_ of angles (which you mentioned). I'm also not convinced they are completely redundant in the poem if you think about the potential imagery.

Comment: Yes, "curve" is a good word to mention in this context.

Comment: I think _bow_ is more synonymous with _sag_ than _bend_; that is, _bowing_ is a certain kind of bending. _Bend_ is more generic and multidimensional: a road or river can bend; a sewing needle can bend; a gooseneck microphone or garden hose can bend. The beams holding up that old roof may be _bowing_, as you say, but the upturned shingles would be _bending_ as they flapped in the high wind.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_warping

Answer (score 11):

Not *bow*!  *Bow*!

You are being caught by a homograph.  The Bridge does not bow (rhymes with "cow"); it bows (rhymes with "lows").  It bends under tension, like an archer's bow.

A *bend* could be a sharp bend, a graceful bend, a zig-zag bend, anything.  It could be natural to the bent item, or it could have been caused by impact, heat, gravity, anything.  It might be permanent.  If an object is *bowed*, it is a graceful distortion over its entire length, caused by a force acting on the ends, and when the force is removed, the object will snap back to its original shape.  If you think of the behavior of Robin Hood's bow or Pablo Casal's bow under the tension of strings, you'll understand.

Comment: I had to remove my upvote after your edit. Your definition of "bow" is too limited. Not all bowed objects will snap back to their original shape. Some are bowed by design (bowed trusses). Some have been bowed by weight and time and will never be restored. I'd also have to question whether "bowed legs" were always a "graceful distortion."

Comment: Wow @joiedevivre, you're really strict, especially given your user-name!  And after Googling images of _tibia varus_, yeah, I think it looks graceful.  In the words of Bartholomew Quint, "I like to go swimmin'/with bow-legged women/and swim between their legs/Swim between their legs/Swim between their legs."

Comment: The force may also be perpendicular along the length such as gravity bowing a shelf.

Comment: @WesToleman -- that seems legit too.  Or an archer bowing an actual bow...

Answer (score 0):

The Shaker song [*Simple Gifts*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Gifts) contains a similar pair of words:

> When true simplicity is gained
>
> To bow and to bend we shan’t be ashamed

I believe this phrase refers to [bowing at the waist](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowing) and kneeling (or *bending the knee*) both physical symbols of submission.

I believe that by using both *bend* and *bow* together, *London Bridge* is referring to both physically warping materials, and also metaphorically to submission in the social/human sense.

In any case, both words have several different meanings as you can tell from the other answers.